# LINQ Getting count on related entities (many to many)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to return the count for the below voters:

`Users` has many to many relationship with `Voters`. I would like to return `Voters` count related to `Users`. I've tried this: `db.Users.Voters.Count()` but fails miserably as it does not recognize `.Voters`.

Is there any way to do this directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `.Voters` is a property of a single `User` object, not a property of the `Users` *collection*. In that case one way would be:

```
db.Users.Sum(user => user.Voters.Count());
```

but that will double-count any voters that are shared by users.  If instead you want a *distinct* count use

```
d.Users.SelectMany(user=>user.Voters).Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
db.Users.Voters != null ? db.Users.Voters.Count() : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SelectMany to extract the matches from the many to many.

Users.SelectMany(x => x.Voters.Where(y => y.Users.Any(z => z.Id == x.Id))).Count()